# Combination of microtype and algorithm package fails to compile

Tags: algorithms, microtype

I try to compile the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[activate=true,final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true]{microtype} % improves font appearance. http://www.khirevich.com/latex/microtype/
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $W_{out}\gets\{w_{out,1},\dots\}$
\State $W_{in}\gets\{w_{in,1},w_{in,2},\dots\}$
\State $g \gets\Call{initialGraph}{W_{in},W_{out}}$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Which fails. However, if I remove microtype from the preambel or just remove the last row of the algorithm, the document compiles as expected.

Any Ideas?

Comment: A work-around: `\State $g \gets{}$\textsc{initialGraph}$(W_{in},W_{out})$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you may want `microtype`'s features in running text, you don't want them in an algorithm, in particular letter spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[activate=true,final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true]{microtype}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\microtypesetup{disable}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $W_{out}\gets\{w_{out,1},\dots\}$
\State $W_{in}\gets\{w_{in,1},w_{in,2},\dots\}$
\State $g \gets\Call{initialGraph}{W_{in},W_{out}}$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Probably “in” and “out” in the subscripts should be enclosed by `\mathrm`.